# exit function(for loop) based on succesfull insertion of data in db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, for-loop

i am trying to build a application for booking timing based on availability
 i am getting device-id based on email-id stored in db , then i am looping through the device id for insertion of booking timing based on which device is free at that time

```
    accounts.findOne({email:mail_back_to}, function(err, res){
    console.log(res.deviceid);
    var dev_id=res.deviceid.split(",");        
    console.log(dev_id);
    for(var i=0;i<dev_id.length;i++){
          console.log(dev_id[i]);
          //dev_details(dev_id[i]);

         async.series([
            function(cb){       
            console.log("in callback");
          var temp=dev_details(dev_id[i]);
          cb('done');
          }],
          function (err,results){
            console.log("callback");
          console.log(results);

           }//function(err,results)   
       );//async.series 



    function dev_details(dev_id){
       dev_checker.findOne({deviceid:dev_id},function(err,res){
       if(res){
        console.log(res);
        console.log("device details are there ");
        return 0;
          }//if
          else {
              dev_checker.insert({deviceid:dev_id,event_name:event_name,event_status:event_status,
                event_description:event_description,event_location:event_location,book_start_time:book_start_time,
                book_end_time:book_end_time,gmt_time:gmt_time,time_zone_offset:time_zone_offset,mail_back_to:mail_back_to},function(err,res){
                  //console.log("values inserted ");
                  if(!res){
                    console.log("some error ");
                  }//if dev_checker.insert
                  else{
                        console.log("values inserted ");
                        console.log(res);


                  }//else dev_checker.insert
                });// dev_checker.insert
           return 1;
          }//else 
       });
    }//dev_details(dev_id)
    break;
     }//for 

             //dev_details(dev_id);   
   });//accounts.findOne()
```

when i am looping throgh it checks each device and insert values if no values is inserted , but i want to exit in case 1st,2nd on any numbered device the value gets inserted, how should i do that

Comment: You might want to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to get the desired behavior. As the db calls are asynchronous, you can't put them in a normal for loop if a break is required

Comment: @ma08 i tried that i used aync series at start of for loop just after                   ` for(var i=0;i<dev_id.length;i++){ `  here is the code                 'async.series([ function(cb){   console.log("in callback");
              var temp=dev_details(dev_id[i]);
              cb('done'); }],         function (err,results){
                console.log("callback");
              console.log(results);             
               }//function(err,results)   
      );//async.series`                  but it gives me undefined for `console.log(results);`           maybe not using it correctly

Comment: Can you properly format it and include the code in your question. It would be easier to debug for people that way.

Comment: @ma08 i have formatted the code and edited it new one ,also i have used some return value so i may be able to something further process using that